# Ender 5 Plus manual screen temperature adjustment

Tags: marlin, firmware, creality-ender-5, temperature, lcd-screen

I want to get my Ender 5 plus to print at 300 °C. As such, I've edited the firmware and increased the `HEATER_0_MAXTEMP` to 315 °C.

In my slicer, I can slice and print at 300 °C, however, I cannot manually adjust the temperature on the LCD screen past the stock setting of 260 °C.

Any help in getting the manual adjustment fixed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are two important considerations before approaching the firmware issue: first, do you have an all-metal, direct-drive extruder?  If you don't, your Bowden tube will melt where it enters the hot end and lead to clogs before you ever reach 300 °C (the same may be true of other plastic parts, if present).  Second: is your heater cartridge rated for high enough power to actually heat the hot end that hot?  There are things like silicone socks that can help here, by keeping the heat break and print cooling fan airflow off the actual hot end -- but this may not even be possible with the stock cartridge for an Ender 5 Plus.

Assuming you've already dealt with those potential issues (and given you can print at this temperature via slicer settings, it seems you have), it seems likely that the Marlin firmware has hard coded limits in the adjustment modules or the LCD input module that prevent manually setting the temperature to a range that is none the less within the reach of the actual control PID.  The only solution for this is likely to be analyzing the source code for the input and manual control modules to find and increase that limit (it may exist in more than one location, and they may not all have a value of 260 °C).

Obviously, you'll want to store an unmodified (or at least a known-working) copy of the firmware before you delve into what might be poorly documented or undocumented parts of the code, but the beauty of open source is that at least this is *possible*.

Comment: From what I read on the internet, the TFT screens operate their own firmware, so it could well be found in the display firmware, not the printer firmware. I haven't had the opportunity to fiddle with TFT displays yet, time to order one.

Answer (score 1):

This printer uses a TFT touch screen to interface with the printer firmware (see e.g. [this question](/q/11431/)). The reason that the updated temperature is not seen by the precompiled firmware of the display. If you look at this specific (custom, not standard) [Marlin fork](https://github.com/InsanityAutomation/Marlin/tree/bugfix-2.0.x/Marlin/src/lcd) you see that the printer firmware and the display firmware are interlinked, this is probably not the case with the default Creality display firmware, it may have hard limits encoded for the temperature.

Looking into the fork mentioned in this answer, you see that the constant `HEATER_0_MAXTEMP` is used in the display source files, so, running this firmware might lift the constrains encountered with custom Marlin and default Creality display software to modify the hotend temperature to the new set maximum.

---

*Please note, running custom firmware on controller board and display should be done at your own risk.*